# Check if large file was uploaded fully into dir before processing

Tags: java, io

I have a cron job that picks up a file from my hot folder and does some crazy stuff. The problem is that it picks up partially uploaded files and starts processing them. Is there a way to check if file was uploaded fully into directory, before processing it.

Comment: What I normally do is upload to one directory, and once the upload is done, move the file to the final directory. Moving a file, at least on Linux, **within the same filesystem**, is a momentary operation as it only requires a change in the directory entries, not a physical move of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the workarounds I figured before is or to rename the file being uploaded to something "original_file.completed" or to create empty "original_file.completed" file after processing finishes and check the existence of that file before work with the original.